# Can't install. I click install Ubuntu and get a black screen

Tags: boot

Please help me. I installed the ISO and used the universal installer to put in a USB drive. When I boot via USB, I click install Ubuntu. Nothing happens. All I get is a black screen. I waited for about 25 minutes, but nothing happened. The computer was stuck the whole time. I ungplugged the USB, which proved that it had to have been something about my laptop because the screen was STILL black. I'm on a Toshiba Satelite with Windows 8. AMD processor. Please help ASAP. Ubuntu looks like a very nice OS, and I'd love to have it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). Section 1. [If you are trying to install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076)

Answer (score 0):

did you try using  the "try ubuntu" option, I had this happen to me when I was attempting to use a flashdrive as a replacement for a hard drive

Answer (score 0):

This could mean that the USB stick you used is corrupted in some way, although no amount of reformatting will fix this. If you do the option to "Try Ubuntu" and then install with the installer on the Desktop then you will see if there is some corruption (if there is it will not load). 
If there is some kind of corruption or issue then it is most likely to be the fault of the USB stick, so I would advise that you try doing it on another USB stick.

I got the same issue and using a different USB stick fixed the problem.